# Proof that the product of 7 successive positive integers is not a square.

Tags: number-theory, contest-math, square-numbers

Can someone give me a hint for this problem (for (8-9) grade student):Proof that the product of 7 successive positive integers is not a square.

(I've found a proof for general case is given in : [here](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/8637/a3b34ded4db991e3288ce295e9b469468292.pdf))

Comment: This question seems to require theory that can not be expected from 9th grade students. Perhaps there is a misunderstandig, either in your interpretation of the question, or in the teachers supposed solution to the problem?

Comment: @Servaes this is the problem from a 9-grade olympiad competition. I don't hace a solution for this answer, but I think it is the hardest problem .Another similar problem in this competition is to prove the product of 8 successive positive integers is not at the form of $n^4$, which is easily to prove by showing that $A=n(n+1)(n+2)(n+3)(n+4)(n+5)(n+6)(n+7)=(n^2+7n)(n^2+7n+6)(n^2+7n+10)(n^2+7n+12)$

Comment: @Zootopia, how do you prove this for product of 8?

Comment: @sku I prove by inequalities.

Answer (score 8):

Assume that the product $n\cdot(n+1)\cdot\ldots(n+6)$ is a square number $m^2$.

Then we proceed with the following steps:

1. Whenever one of the factors is divisible by a prime number $p\geq7$, that prime must occur with an even power in that number.
2. The sequence $n,\ldots,n+6$ contains a subsequence $u,u+2,u+4$ of odd numbers.
3. Exactly one of $u,u+2,u+4$ is divisible by 3, and at most one of $u,u+2,u+4$ is divisible by 5.
4. As a consequence of (1), each element $x$ of $\{u,u+2,u+4\}$ is either

   - a square (in which case $x\equiv1\pmod8$),
   - $3$ times a square (in which case $x\equiv3\pmod8$),
   - $5$ times a square (in which case $x\equiv5\pmod8$), or
   - $15$ times a square (in which case $x\equiv7\pmod8$).
5. As a consequence of (2), the only possibility is $u=a^2$, $u+2=3b^3$ and $u+4=5c^2$.
6. Now $u+3$ is neither divisible by $3$ nor by $5$, so $u+3$ is the product of a power of $2$ and an odd square (by (1)).
7. Since $u\equiv1\pmod8$, we have $u+3\equiv4\pmod8$, which can only happen if $u+3$ is disivible by $4$ but not by $8$.
8. (6) and (7) imply that $u+3$ is itself a square. Since it has distance $3$ to $u=a^2$, this implies that $u=1$ and thus $m^2 = 1\cdot\ldots\cdot7 = 5040$, a contradiction since $5040$ is not a square.

Comment: very nice solution !.

Comment: Good work! I believe this leads to a full solution. But how did you exclude possibilities such $u=5A^2$, $u+2=15B^2$, $u+4=C^2$ and other such shifts? I didn't see it, but I like to think you can anyway find a similar arguments to cover those other cases as well.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen: If $u=5A^2$ and $u+2=15B^2$, then both $u$ and $u+2$ are divisible by $5$ which is impossible. Other shifts follow similarly. (Okay, in #5, I should have written "As a consequence of (2) **and (3)**...)

Comment: Oh yeah! I missed that. Thanks :-).